# Is this router ok?

Tags: cisco, router

I administer a small business of around 20 people. They are wanting to get some faster internet to get the youtube and the torrents. I was looking at buying a CRS-3 from cisco. Does anyone here have experience with these? They look like good value.

Answer (score 4):

Unless your router is 15 years old, upgrading your router is unlikely to get you faster internet. If your aim is faster internet, you need to upgrade your internet connection first. For 20 people, any router that your ISP can provide should be fine.

Comment: AOL says they cant provide a crs-3 I have to order through our cisco rep.

Comment: +1.  I would only add he might need to upgrade the router if they are using something trashy like a netgear that will blow up once it's NAT table fills from torrents.  I've seen this require hard reboots on those routers even in a 2 PC home network.  DD-WRT can relieve this though.

Comment: @Matthew - my point was, don't bother upgrading your router. Upgrade your internet first. Upgrading your router on its own won't get you *any* extra speed.

Comment: I dunno if you've noticed, but this is the CRs 3 -http://newsroom.cisco.com/dlls/2010/prod_030910.html  Obvious troll is obvious.

Comment: Having seen the specifications, I don't think that a single CRS3 would provide an adequate LoC throughput for your organisation. (http://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/e4qjd/in_case_you_were_wondering_this_is_the_most/c15b9z3)

Comment: Ugh I should have recognized the Carrier Router System acronym first, as I worked for Cisco when they made a big deal about launching it.

Comment: My crappy joke failed.